# Kotlin multiplatform project is using old complied code

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am experimenting with kotlin multiplatform code I got some sample code running but have made changes to that code now. Every time i compile my project the old kotlin code is run instead of the new code with my changes. How do i make a clean build with the new kotlin code? i have tried invalidating the caches and restarting android, uninstalling the application, running gradle build androidJar, androidMainClasses,clean all haven't worked. Any ideas?  When i try to change the name of the method i get `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method aboutMe` it can't find the new method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete my whole build folder and have it rebuild everything

Answer (score 1):

A new build should clear out old compiled code that has changed, but if it doesn't, run `gradle clean` (either from a command line with the `gradlew` wrapper or via the gradle tasks window in Android Studio). This will remove the build directory which will cause the next build to rebuild everything and should eliminate cached code issues.